# Retrofit request login: HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to login into my Spring Webserver on the localhost.
Use Postman I have no problem,see example:

POST localhost:8080/login | Body | raw | JSON:

```
{
"username":"john",
"password":"12345"
}
```

No I like to replcate this request in an Android environment using Retrofit.
I'm new to Retrofit and for me right now it's a guessing game, to find out what is going wrong.

I get is null as response:

```
11/11 15:47:42: Launching 'app' on Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE API 22.
Install successfully finished in 3 s 181 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ssl.loginretrofit/com.ssl.loginretrofit.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 13739 on device 'Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_S7_FE_API_22 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10065: Read-only file system
W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.601ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 237(42KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 47% free, 1142KB/2MB, paused 16.583ms total 23.474ms
I/System.out: -- ON CREATE --
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb40f19c0, tid 13739
D/Atlas: Validating map...
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae85a2e0, tid 13757
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae834dc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834dc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae8393f0)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834dc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae8393f0)
I/System.out: -- ON CLICK --
    -- createAuthToken --
    AuthToken: john:12345
    -- CHECK LOGIN DETAILS --
I/System.out: Check call response: retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@38dc3f4f
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST http://10.0.2.2:8080/login
    Content-Length: 0
    Authorization: Basicam9objoxMjM0NQ==
    --> END POST (0-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 401 http://10.0.2.2:8080/login (15ms)
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Expires: 0
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Type: application/json
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2022 14:47:53 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Keep-Alive: timeout=60
    Connection: keep-alive
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"timestamp":"2022-11-11T14:47:53.029+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","path":"/login"}
    <-- END HTTP (97-byte body)
I/System.out: -- RESPONSE --
    response.body: null
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ssl.loginretrofit, PID: 13739
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.matches(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.ssl.loginretrofit.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:65)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I tried many things like changing the endpoint, BaseURL, GsonBuilder, etc.

This in my Main.class

```
package com.ssl.loginretrofit;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private EditText usernameTxt, passTxt;
    private String username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("-- ON CREATE --");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        usernameTxt = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        passTxt = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("-- ON CLICK --");
                username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
                password = passTxt.getText().toString();

                String authToken = createAuthToken(username, password);
                checkLoginDetails(authToken);
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkLoginDetails(String authToken) {
        System.out.println("-- CHECK LOGIN DETAILS --");
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
        final InterfaceAPI api = retrofit.create(InterfaceAPI.class);

        Call<String> call = api.checkLogin(authToken);
        System.out.println("Check call response: "+call);  

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                System.out.println("-- RESPONSE --");
                System.out.println("response.body: " +response.body());

                if (response.body().matches("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Logged In ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // set shared prefs...
                    // next intent
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credentials :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("-- FAILURE --");
                Log.e("TAG", t.toString());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }


    private String createAuthToken(String username, String password) {
        byte [] data = new byte[0];
        try{
            data = (username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // check later
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Basic" + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```

Right here is the endpoint:

```
package com.ssl.loginretrofit;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface InterfaceAPI {

    // @POST("/login")
    @POST("user.account/login") // might not be the right endpoint?
    Call<String> checkLogin(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
}
```

RetrofitCleintInstance

```
package com.ssl.loginretrofit;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClientInstance {
        //private static String API_BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/testProject/webresources/";
        private static String API_BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static Gson gson;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient() // might want to take out to get the default
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: as the log say your response body return null `response.body: null` for a better logging i suggest to use `http logging interceptor` to see log what retrofit doing

Comment: I've added OkHttp: Interceptor and it seems I get a Unauthorized error:
"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","path":"/login"}
Is it posible that my authToken is not correct?

Comment: yes i suppose your authToken is still not correct

Comment: Have a look at the headers sent in postman, and then make sure you are sending the same via retrofit.

Comment: I notest that I'm using the Body instead of the Header in Postman, but if I change my endpiont from: Call<String> checkLogin(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
to Call<String> checkLogin(@Body String authToken); to I still get 401.

Comment: You need to pass the username and password to the endpoint in the same way that you do in Postman. So something like `Call<String> checkLogin(@Body UserAndPassObject body)`

Comment: @POST("user.account/login") is probably the wrong route, you didn't need `user.account` in the working postman implementation.